# Google Maps API - Changing the Column the Gradient References?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, styles, maps, google-fusion-tables

Link to gradient picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR4E7.png

Using google fusion tables I created a map and have set the features so that it displays a color gradient based on a value in column "M" (see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR4E7.png ).

Using google maps API I have the code below to display my map as a layer and show the gradient just as it does in fusion tables.- The question I have, is how do I change the column google fusion tables uses for the gradient (in this case column "M"), let's say, to column "P" without having to go back to the fusion tables GUI each time?

I have been researching this for a couple of days and can't find working example code. any help would be appreciated

```
 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col11",
    from: "MY MAP ID HERE",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2,

  }
```